# PHP ERROR When viewing previous and next month calender

Tags: php, codeigniter, calendar

In here it displays the calendar but when ever I click next or previous link it show this error:

> Object not found! The requested URL was not found on this server. The link on the referring page seems to be wrong or outdated. Please inform the author of that page about the error. If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster. Error 404

Please someone help me!

**Project name: ci_series**

### config.php

I set the base url as http://localhost/ci_series/'

```
         $config['index_page'] = '';
```

I used cordelginer framework.My welcome controller is the one    defaultly loading.

### welcome.php

```
     <?php

      class Welcome extends CI_Controller {


    function index()
    {

        $this -> display( $year=null, $month=null);

    }
    //display function
function display($year=null, $month=null)
    {
        $conf= array( 
            'start_day'=>'monday',
            'show_next_prev' => true,
            'next_prev_url' => base_url(). 'display'

        );
        $this->load->library('calendar',$conf);
        echo $this->calendar->generate(  $year, $month);
    }

}
```

Comment: `'next_prev_url' => base_url('welcome/display')`

Comment: I tried this but still I am getting the same error

Comment: Try with `index.php` i.e. `'next_prev_url'   => 'http://example.com/index.php/welcome/display/'`

Comment: OMG! Thank you sooo much! It really works!You saved my life

Comment: You probably need better set code in `.htaccess` file to achieve URLs working without `index.php` within.

Comment: Or maybe is problem that calendar class preference expects slash at the end so if everything is ok with your `.htaccess`, this would be correct path too: `base_url('welcome/display') . '/'`

Comment: Thank u soo much... :)